# RX 580 (8GB) Losing Monitor Signal Under Heavy Tasks

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, display, hardware-failure

I just noticed that I keep on losing monitor signals when I do GPU Heavy Tasks like using Adobe Products (PS, PR, AE) and playing games. My computer is totally fine when I'm on normal tasks like browsing the web and watching videos. Are there any problems with the latest drivers for RX 580?

```
CPU: i7 4790
GPU: Sapphire Nitro+ 8GB RX 580
RAM: 16GB DDR3
PSU: Corsair VS 550
OS: Windows 10 Pro Build 20H2
AMD Drivers: 20.12.1
Storage: 1.5TB HDD, 500GB SSD
```

I only play Dota 2.

Comment: To what GPU port is the monitor connected?

Comment: Through HDMI. I think I fixed the problem when I throttled down the power consumption of my GPU through the AMD Software. It looks like my PSU cannot keep up with the demand of my GPU when under heavy tasks.